# What's the arity of the factorial and exponential operations?

Tags: soft-question, exponentiation, factorial

I'm having a conflict with the concept of arity, I've read [that the factorial is a unary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) and also that the exponentiation is a [binary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_%28mathematics%29) but I feel there's something strange, the definition for exponentiation is:

$$b^n = \underbrace{b \times \cdots \times b}_n$$

And the definition for factorial is:

$$n ! = n \times...\times 1   $$

So, for both exponentiation ($x^n$) and factorial ($n!$)  shouldn't $n$ be the arity? Since we need to perform $n$ multiplications in order to evaluate it? With one exception for $0!=1$ which may be a unary operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When we evaluate the exponential $a^b$ we need two inputs $a$ and $b$. When we evaluate the factorial $n!$ we only need one input $n$.

Comment: Oh, I thought it had something to do with the number of operations it is needed for evaluating it.

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity